# How to upload raw XML data via POST to URL in Talend?

Tags: talend

I am trying to upload an xml file to a url so that I can retrieve response in XML.

I tried using thttprequest
[image]

But it says, "Can't write output after reading input."
What am I doing wrong?

The request.xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<request xmlns="http://www.isinet.com/xrpc42"
src="app.id=PartnerApp,env.id=PartnerAppEnv,partner.email=EmailAddress" >
  <fn name="LinksAMR.retrieve">
 <list>
  <!-- WHO'S REQUESTING -->
 <map>
 <val name="username">username</val>
 <val name="password">test</val>
 </map>
 <!-- WHAT'S REQUESTED -->
  <map>
 <list name="WOS">
  <val>timesCited</val>
  <val>ut</val>
  <val>doi</val>
  <val>sourceURL</val>
  <val>citingArticlesURL</val>
  <val>relatedRecordsURL</val>
  </list>
  </map> <!--end "return_data" -->
  <!-- LOOKUP DATA -->
 <map>
<!-- QUERY "cite_1" -->
 <map name="cite_1">
 <val name="atitle">article title string</val>
 <val name="stitle">full journal title</val>
 <val name="issn">1234-5678</val>
 <val name="vol">12</val>
 <val name="issue">12</val>
 <val name="year">2008</val>
 <val name="doi">doi_string</val>
 <val name="ut">isi_ut_num</val>
<val name="spage">1234</val>
<!-- authors list can be used to specify multiple authors -->
    <list name="authors">
  <val>First, AU</val>
  <val>Second, AU</val>
 <val>Third, AU</val>
 </list>
  </map> <!-- end of cite_id-->
 <-- QUERY "cite_2"
  <map name="cite_2">
 ...
  </map>
 -->
  </map> <!-- end of citations -->
   </list>
  </fn>
  </request>
```

I am posting to the web of science url
https://ws.isiknowledge.com/cps/xrpc

Normally, if there was a mistake, I should be getting a response that something went wrong in XML. I am not even getting that.

I tried using tRestClient but I am unsure of how to upload a file to the url through it. Also this post might hold some clues. https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-31574

Comment: I have heard that thttprequest component needs updating. If so, can there be any workaround for this. Preferably using tJava components.

Comment: Can you post some information about the web service you are trying to post to and some example of the XML you are attempting to post to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also upload a string instead of the file. But for this you need to use tJava_Row, since tJava can't work with one row at a time.

```
URL url = new URL("https://ws.isiknowledge.com/cps/xrpc");
StringBuilder response_content = new StringBuilder();
String data=row1.content;
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
 OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
 wr.write(data);
 wr.flush();

 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  String line;
   while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  //  System.out.println(line);
    response_content.append(line);
   }
 String output=response_content.toString();
 wr.close();
 rd.close();
 row2.content=(output);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was better than mine. I don't need to create two jobs now - one for writing the request and the other for reading the response

Answer (score 0):

I used tJava component

```
URL url = new URL("https://ws.isiknowledge.com/cps/xrpc");
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.setDoInput(true);
c.setUseCaches(false);
c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
c.connect();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int cbuffer = 0;
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new     FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\dhiraj\\workspace\\request.xml"));
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
while ((cbuffer = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     os.write(buffer, 0, cbuffer);
}
os.flush();
os.close();
is.close();
if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == c.getResponseCode()) {
    is = new BufferedInputStream(
    c.getInputStream());
    while ((cbuffer = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    content.append(new String(
    buffer, 0, cbuffer));
    }
    is.close();
  } else {
    System.err.println(c.getResponseCode() + ":" + c.getResponseMessage());
}
row1.ResponseContent = content.toString();
c.disconnect();
```